# AutoLayout: Centering two views in code causes constraint exception?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, autolayout

Short version: Creating a `NSLayoutAttributeCenterX` constraint always causes a constraint failure. Why?

I have a `UITextField` subclass which behaves as a search textbox. You tap the box and a list of items appear, the items are filtered by what you type. Like this:

[image]

The `UITextField` subclass is responsible for creating and displaying the view of items. The center of the list should match the textfield's center. So, I set my constraint like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *hugCenter = 
   [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.searchContainerView
                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:self
                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                               multiplier:1.0
                                 constant:0.0];
```

This invariably leads to the error:

> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
>   NSLayoutConstraint:0x9a5e1a0 UIView:0x9a5ba40.centerX ==
>   SearchTextField:0x7154a40.centerX

For testing I've made my scene as simple as possible -- 1 textfield on a view controller:

[image]

Why does this cause a constraint error?

Comment: Continuing to investigate: this seems to be related to the fact that the textField is centered horizontally in its superview. I still don't understand why this should matter. The list should center on the textField, the textField should center on the superview. I'm not seeing how they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: In the console, right before "Will attempt to recover..", you should have seen a list of all the relevant constraints. Pls copy/paste that into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:` somewhere?

Comment: I've tried setting it to `NO` in the `UITextField` subclass and the created list view as well. Made no difference. I obviously can't set it on the root view for the scene though since setting it from a subview would certainly be a bad idea.